Editing the size of partitions of the disk where the OS is mounted
I'm using a Linux OS that is a built using Ubuntu. I want to decrease the size of partition 4 and increase the size of my home partition i.e partition 2, however my OS is installed in this disk, so is it possible to edit the partition size of this disk in which my OS is installed.


Please Edit your question and add the output of df -hx squashfs and mount | grep sd

Does this answer your question? How to resize partitions?
